# Can't click on element in selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to click on this element in selenium for login but it wont work for me. This is my code for it

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='otherTile']")).Click();
```

But it wont work. Here is the html code for it.

[image]

Comment: .Click() should be lowercase .click()